# CSS font antialiasing is "inventing" new colors?

Tags: css, vuetify.js, quasar-framework

I have two texts with, according to the "Computed" CSS properties, the same CSS properties. One antialiases in greyscale, the other in color. On the left we have Vuetify v3, on the right Quasar v2. Vuetify renders the text a bit nicer (although opions could vary..). Both are rendered in Chrome 109. I've tried to add `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`, but I believe that this is an outdated property, and Chrome seems to ignore it alltogether.

Quasar did not have the text-rendering property, so I added `text-rendering: optimizelegibility !important;` here myself. This however, did not seem to change the output.

The only thing I could not control for is the font itself. Both Vuetify and Quasar come with Roboto prepackaged.

[image: Antialiasing, grey vs. colored]

Computed CSS properties:
[image: Computed CSS properties]

What is going on here, why are these text rendered differently? and how can we force the anti-aliasing to not "invent" these extra colors?

Comment: I've discovered a similar issue and perhaps this doesn't have to do with Vuetify/Quasar. For me, this is occurring when the text element has a set background-color, vs when it has a transparent background. Transparent background = grayscale, set background-color = subpixel. You can even set the text element's background color to the same of its parent, and watch it completely change rendering (and in my case, annoying change to an entirely different looking color). I also think this likely only occurs on Windows, though I haven't tested other platforms.

Comment: @addMitt: I've been bugged by the very same problem. I attempted to reproduce your suggestion, but for me, wrapping the text on a span and setting it to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` didn't change a thing. Am I missing something here? And yes, I'm on Windows.

Comment: @devouredelysium perhaps the container needs to be a block element and not inline? Unfortunately I do not have the previous example anymore. I think I pivoted to something that wouldn't have this issue. I wouldn't be surprised if the browser behaved differently at this point, either.